# Small AC-DC conversion/amplification

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, ac-dc

So essentially looking for the most efficient and effective way to take a 3V 50hz AC signal and convert it to an 11-33V DC signal (any voltage between 11 and 33 works for an input to embedded pc) . I have looked into a couple different options such has bridge rectifier with a cap for small ripple then into amplifier or an open loop comparator with the rails set in the 11-33V range (positive and negative) then just do square wave rectification (no cap so no ripple) or even setting the high and low voltages of the comparator to say 15v low and 25v high which both register as high for the embedded pc digital input. (Not sure if this one will work, haven’t messed around with opamp comparators and not sure if the ‘low’ voltage can still be a positive DC value)

Comment: I'm confused. Are you stuck with 3 VAC? What's creating it? Is it a transformer hooked to mains? Or what, exactly? It's a lot easier if you just get a transformer from mains that produces a higher voltage. (Or one that converts 3 VAC to something like 12 VAC.)

Comment: It is the output of a sensor that is used as an input for an embedded PC but the PC only registers 11-33 VDC as high from its input pins

Comment: That may be my own mistake in reading you, then. So this isn't for power. You want to measure the magnitude of the AC?

Comment: It may help clarify if you post the type of controller (embeded PC) you are using. It sounds something like a PLC with 24V logic inputs. And post a datasheet for the sensor with the 3VAC output. You are asking how to condition the signal from the sensor to match the input range of the controller.

Comment: Yea so unfortunately I was not the one doing the ordering and my group got sensors with incorrect output signals that I have to “make work” now. All I need is the output of the sensors (3 VAC) to be within the range of 11-33 VDC when transmitting a signal. The PC just needs a yes it’s transmitting or no it is not. When the sensor is not transmitting a signal 0V is registered as low for the PC. When it is transmitting a signal, that signal must be between the 11-33 V DC to register as high for the PC. Does that answer the question?

Comment: https://www.beckhoff.com/en-us/products/ipc/embedded-pcs/cx5100-intel-atom/cx5140.html The embedded PC

Comment: https://www.alliedelec.com/product/banner-engineering/s183eq1/70246442/  Sensor

Comment: Is it 3V AC with a DC offset voltage?

Comment: @EarthLord What is needed or what is supplied? As far as I can tell from the data sheet, it is just a 3 V AC signal supplied and it needs to be an 11-33V DC signal. Honestly it doesn’t even have to be a DC signal, it can have a DC offset of say 20V then have a 6V peak to peak ac signal with that DC offset. As long as it stays between the 11-33V range it registers as high. The limiting factor is when the sensor is not transmitting, the output must be below 11V ie no DC offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the premise that the output is 3V AC is incorrect. But looking at the datasheet i can see where the assumption is coming from:

[image: Output data]

<sub>Source: [Datasheet](https://assets.alliedelec.com/v1549022639/Datasheets/ec2bb0d8ac5a59128e98672c77ebc611.pdf)</sub>

Notice the output configuration is a three-wire connection with a SPST solid-state ac switch. This might be easier to understand looking at the wiring diagram, also provided in the datasheet:

[image: Wiring diagram]

Wire 1 and 3 are for the supply voltage of 20V-250V ac. The output signal of the sensor is basically the state of the switch either being ON or OFF. This output can be used with wire 4 connected to the load or in other words, your circuit.

The most important rating is the maximum output current of 300mA. I believe the "ON-state saturation voltage" of 3V that is mentioned at 300mA is just the voltage drop across the switch.

So in practice, the output voltage is approximately equal to the supply voltage in ON-state. Depending on the supply voltage, you could just use a regular rectifier for your PC input then.

Comment: Good find! If this sensor works on 20-250V AC, I bet it has a rectifier followed by a high voltage linear regulator as power supply, so then why would it not work on 24VDC? That would give the DC output the OP wants directly...

Comment: If that’s the case why wouldn’t the data sheet incorporate an AC or DC input? (Forgive my questions I just got into the actual field and still learning applied concepts, school doesn’t exactly teach you that part and I am just now graduating in April)

Comment: @Graduate In general the datasheet should incorporate this. Using parts outside their specification is usually not a good idea. Although using a low DC voltage with the sensor will probably not do any damage to it.

Comment: @bobflux The sensor could be using a SSR with a SCR or TRIAC based output. That would mean that the SSR will not turn Off using a DC supply

Comment: The specifications very much sound like something similar to this: https://www.vishay.com/docs/84798/vo4254.pdf

Comment: Yeah, if it's triac then... no DC.

Answer (score 0):

Since the aim is to sense if there is a 3V AC signal output from the sensor or not by a 11-33V DC input, one approach could be:

Sensor output -> Half wave rectifier (diode) -> RC low pass filter with say 2 Hz cutoff (10k Ohm and 10 uF) -> a 12V supply comparator (LM321 for example) -> input of embedded PC.

The idea is to create a DC offset of the AC output with half wave rectifier, isolate only the DC part of it, compare it to a reference voltage set by say a potential divider and then give the comparator's output to the embedded PC.

The above system would work if there is a 0V signal from your sensor when its not sensing. Also there would be some latency to change the digital output once 3V AC output is on/off due to the low pass filter.

Comment: So that was one of the things I mentioned in the original post (half wave rectifier or full wave bridge rectifier with capacitor to dampen the ripple) then to amplifier or comparator. Would this be the most efficient way though? All of the ways mentioned would get the job done, the question is just pertaining to efficiency or if there was another way I hadn’t thought about.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe would be something like the first schematic as a minimum circuit. But your sensor can have different voltages applied, so you're not really limited to 3 VAC (the datasheet says 20-250 VAC). The S183EQ1 has no outputs and is intended to be used as a series element in a control loop. I'd be wiling to bet that the sensor will operate at 24 VDC and you can use it directly on the input of the controller like the lower schematics. Size the resistor to get the output voltage range you want (100 Ohm seems to work well in simulation).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frW909.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQtLNU.png)</sup>